# popWin() in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

in magento 1 for open window we use this code

```
<a href="" onclick="popWin('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('example/order/orderitems') ?>', 
                        'gallery', 'width=1500,height=700,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" ><?php echo $this->__('Items Ordered');?> </a>
```

In magento 2 how can i open popup window on click in admin panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your module view > adminhtml

in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
            'popupWindow':  'mage/popup-window',
         }
     }
};
```

In your template file

```
<a href="#"
   data-mage-init='{"popupWindow": {"windowURL":"<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/order/orderitems')?>","windowName":"orderitems","width":1500,"height":700,"top":0,"left":0,"resizable":1,"scrollbars":1}}'
   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Item Order') ?>"
   class="action-default scalable add primary">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Item order') ?></span>
</a>
```

This code is working for me